# How to extract all links on a page using crawler4j?

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, web-crawler, crawler4j

I am implementing a web crawler and I am using Crawler4j library. I am not getting all the links on a web site .
I tried to extract all the links on one page using Crawler4j and missed some links.

Crawler4j version : crawler4j-3.3

Url I used :http://testsite2012.site90.com/frontPage.html

No. of links on this page : almost 60 and 4-5 among them are repeating

No. of links crawler4j gave: 23

[this](http://ideone.com/3YTsR) is list of URLs on page and [this](http://ideone.com/hGb57) is list of URLs given by Crawler4j.

I looked in 'HtmlContentHandler.java' file using by crawler4j to extract the links . In this only links associated with 'src' and 'href' links are being extracted .

I find the difference between these files. Crawler4j is missing the links which are not associated with 'src' or 'href' attribute and which are under the 'script' tag.
[this](http://ideone.com/buIZv) is the list of links which crawler4j didn't crawl .

How can i extract all the links on this page ?
Do I need to do string manipulation(like findding 'http' ) on HTML parsed page or should I change code of 'HtmlContentHandler.java' file ?

Which is best way ?

Even if I do string manipulation and extract all links on this page but Crawler4j is crawling the website using the links crawled by itself and won't in such case it miss some pages ?

Comment: Use Jsoup parser. Easy and neat.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to locate links.

You can look [here](http://skolaprogramiranja.com/category/regular-expressions/) for an example.

Comment: I am already using regular expression and using regular expression in 'shouldVisit()'control which page to fetch,parse. It doesn't control which kind of links to extract on already fetched page .

I hope you understand what I am trying to say . Do you ?

Comment: What i meant is that you use Reg Exp for finding the strings you need as well (like all strings that start with 'http://'). Look at the sample i linked at the 'getStrWithPattern()' method

Comment: ok. But problem is say I want to crawl a website .If there are 5 links on main page of web site and crawler4j extract 3 (I 'll use regex to extract remaining links) then Crawler4j will keep crawling website based on those 3 links not 5.
In that case it might miss some pages. 
What to do in that case ?

Comment: Can we add those 2 links at runtime in 'toCrawl' list of crawler4j ? if yes , how ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand What is preventing you from adding those 2 links to the list? Isn't the list under your control? It doesn't matter how you extraxted the links, once you have them you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: No that list isn't under my control. I am not such expert in it. If you know how to control that list , please let me know .

Comment: My classes are almost same as basic example code given here .
http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/basic/